# Errors when unpacking binutils-common

Tags: kali-linux, dpkg, binutils

So when i update kali linux with sudo apt update it shows this

```
Get:1 file:/run/live/medium kali-last-snapshot InRelease
Ign:1 file:/run/live/medium kali-last-snapshot InRelease
Get:2 file:/run/live/medium kali-last-snapshot Release [7,354 B]
Get:2 file:/run/live/medium kali-last-snapshot Release [7,354 B]
Get:3 file:/run/live/medium kali-last-snapshot Release.gpg
Ign:3 file:/run/live/medium kali-last-snapshot Release.gpg
Get:4 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling InRelease [41.2 kB]
Reading package lists... Done
E: Release file for file:/run/live/medium/dists/kali-last-snapshot/Release is not valid yet (invalid for another 24d 7h 37min 13s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.
E: Release file for http://http.kali.org/kali/dists/kali-rolling/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 47d 21h 22min 3s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.
```

and when i upgrade with sudo apt full-upgrade -y it shows me this

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 binutils : Depends: binutils-common (= 2.41-4) but 2.40.90.20230714-2 is installed
 binutils-x86-64-linux-gnu : Depends: binutils-common (= 2.41-4) but 2.40.90.20230714-2 is installed
 libbinutils : Depends: binutils-common (= 2.41-4) but 2.40.90.20230714-2 is installed
 libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.37-7) but 2.37-6 is installed
 libc6-i386 : Depends: libc6 (= 2.37-7) but 2.37-6 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

and when i try sudo apt --fix-broken install show me this

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  binutils-common libc6
Suggested packages:
  glibc-doc libnss-nis libnss-nisplus
The following packages will be upgraded:
  binutils-common libc6
2 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 452 not upgraded.
39 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/5,265 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,024 B disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Reading changelogs... Done
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 418244 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libc6_2.37-7_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libc6:amd64 (2.37-7) over (2.37-6) ...
Setting up libc6:amd64 (2.37-7) ...
Setting up libstdc++6:amd64 (13.2.0-2) ...
(Reading database ... 418244 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../binutils-common_2.41-4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking binutils-common:amd64 (2.41-4) over (2.40.90.20230714-2) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/binutils-common_2.41-4_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 unable to make backup link of './usr/share/locale/ms/LC_MESSAGES/gprof.mo' before installing new version: Input/output error
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/binutils-common_2.41-4_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

i have a kali live boot with persistence and this the third time reinstall it
i need ur help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set your system’s date and time — your system’s date is in the past. On top of that, your storage seems to be broken.